# play 2.2 webjars requirejs jquery integration

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, playframework-2.2, webjars

After upgrade to play 2.2, I cannot make requirejs work as before.

It seems to me that the requirejs is not initialized or configured correctly. I tried to follow https://github.com/mariussoutier/play-angular-require-seed, but I cannot even make the simplest case to work.

jquery can be located correctly in main.js, but require(['jquery'].....) does not work in  tag.

If someone could help me with this, it would be appreciated a lot.

webjars definition

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  "org.webjars" % "jquery" % "1.10.2",
  "org.webjars" % "requirejs" % "2.1.1",
  "org.webjars" % "webjars-play_2.10" % "2.2.0"
)     

resolvers += "typesafe" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/repo"

requireJs += "main.js"

requireJsShim += "main.js"
```

main.js

```
 (function(requirejs) {
      "use strict";

      // -- PROD RequireJS config --
      requirejs.config({
        shim: {
          "jquery": { exports: "$" }
        },
        paths: {
          "jquery": ["/webjars/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min"]
        }
      });
      // It works fine here        
      require(["jquery"], function($) {
        console.log($);
      });
    })(requirejs);
```

index.scala.html

```
@(title: String)

<html>
    <body>
    <script src='/lib/require.js' type='text/javascript' data-main="/assets/javascripts/main"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        require(["jquery"], function($) {
            console.log($);
            });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

main.js is loaded, and the error message in the console is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'require' of object [object Object] is not a function
```

**Edit**
The key here is to understand the AMD concept. Although two snippets in  tag are placed one after the other, they are not guaranteed execute in order. Therefore, when the second snippet runs, the requirejs may not be configured yet.

```
<script src='webjars/requirejs/2.1.8/require.js' type='text/javascript' data-main="javascripts/main"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    // Second snippet
    require(['jquery'], function($) {return $;});
</script>
```

To fix this, we have two different approaches:

1. Include the javascript code of the second snippet in main.js (specified in data-main) and Use require(['dependencies'], function() {// do second.js})
2. Do not specify data-main field when including requirejs, and do all the configuration in the second part.

IMHO, the first approach is preferred and is the exact one used in the sample project https://github.com/mariussoutier/play-angular-require-seed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qualifying my reply, definitely not an expert...

In your index.scala.html page, you're trying to use a script that's loaded asynchronously.  That will give you random results, because it might very well not be loaded in time.

From the RequireJS site:

> Note: the script tag
>   require.js generates for your data-main module includes the async
>   attribute. This means that you cannot assume that the load and
>   execution of your data-main script will finish prior to other scripts
>   referenced later in the same page.
>
> For example, this arrangement will fail randomly when the
>   require.config path for the 'foo' module has not been set prior to it
>   being require()'d later:

```
<script data-main="scripts/main" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/other.js"></script>

// contents of main.js:
require.config({
    paths: {
        foo: 'libs/foo-1.1.3'
    }
});

// contents of other.js:

// This code might be called before the require.config() in main.js
// has executed. When that happens, require.js will attempt to
// load 'scripts/foo.js' instead of 'scripts/libs/foo-1.1.3.js'
require( ['foo'], function( foo ) {

});
```

Also of note... in the example you linked to, this problem is avoided, because all the usage of "require" happens in main*.js

So what I believe you need to do, is to wrap JavaScript code contained within your second script in an event handler which is listening for an event such as window.onload or DOMContentLoaded event, to delay the execution until those events have fired (and all  will be present and correct).

References:

- http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#data-main
- [Javascript async loading and order of execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299922/javascript-async-loading-and-order-of-execution)
- https://github.com/mariussoutier/play-angular-require-seed/blob/master/app/views/index.scala.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clarification. I thought all the dependencies in require(['jquery'], ....) would be loaded by specifying data-main and then I could use them in the second <script> tag. Now I kinda understand the concept of async module loading. In order to make the whole thing work, I need to either include the snippet in other.js within the data-main or configure the requirejs in other.js directly.